# HTML link is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using one jquery that is multilayer menu but I met some problem with the link.

jQuery: http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/

The JS Array Demo: http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/demo/basicjs/basicjs.html

The link is not clickable when I implement into my code.

For example, 
in the demo site, click "devices" -> "Mobile phones" -> "super smart phones",

I put one link in "super smart phones" but this link is no clickable.

The page will not be direct to '/devices/mobile/supersmartphones/' which I defined in a tag.

Here is some parts of my code:

```
<a href="/devices/mobile/supersmartphones/">
    <i class="floatRight undefined"></i>Super Smart Phone</a>

.mlpm_w a {
display: block;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 1.5em;
line-height: 1em;
padding: .2em .2em;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

.mlpm_w a:hover {
color: #ffe;
}

.mlpm_w .floatRight {
float: right;
}

title: 'All Product',
    icon: 'fa fa-reorder',
    items: [
        {
            name: 'Mobile Phone',
            link: '/device/mobile/',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Mobile Phone',
                    items: [
                        {
                            name: 'Super Smart Phone',
                            link: '/device/mobile/supersmartphones/'
                        },
```

I don't know where is the problem, it's hard to explain, and sorry about that.

Thank you for you solving my problems.

Comment: It's because js you are using is removing that href value and replacing it with #

Comment: But I already change # to the real link that I'd like to redirect.

Comment: But js code again rewriting that.. if you need more help i can do it for you

Comment: can you create a fiddle for us to see what problem your facing

Comment: when you inspect the link on the test page - you´ll see that the href has no value ( no point to go ) `#` - Your Js is overwriting the link. So you have to change the links in your js markup. The Css is not the Problem :)

Comment: You will need to change js code for that... :)

Comment: I attached the javascript that I use, please help to check where should I revise.

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2zRuv/) for this issue. I changed the Super smart phone menu entry to point to google.com. Left mouse menu does nothing but right click and open in new tab does open google.com. Sorry mate I think you should contact the maker of the plugin to sort out how to use the thing... :-/

Comment: Is it possible the Js's problem, I will try HTML one to check if the problem is still exists.

Comment: I don't think it will change anything. In your development you used the JSON version and in my fiddle I used the HTML version and they both show the same symptoms so I think you better contact the developer.

Comment: Can't we fix the problem ourselves ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set preventItemClick false to handle menu to connect custom url.

```
$('#menu').multilevelpushmenu( { preventItemClick: false  } );
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2zRuv/2/)

Comment: In my code, the menu will back to initialized one we I click the link. I can't reproduce it on the Fiddle.

Comment: ok! so this fix works as expected? or u facing another issue.?

Comment: Sorry not able to follow it, will u give me fiddle or detail.

Comment: It's okay, I will try to figure out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin handles events using its own event handlers that you may customize. For example, if you want to open a new tab with your content you would do it like this:

```
$('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({
    onItemClick: function() {
        $item = arguments[2]
        var URL = $item.find( 'a' ).attr("href");
        window.open(URL,'_blank');
    }
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rPD5b/)